# Bootstrap sliding columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am trying to figure out how to create sliding columns/boxes (not carousels) like in this site (second section horizontally):
https://www.resumerepublic.com/

Lets say I have 5 columns. I want to render 3 of those initially: 1 2 3
and have a pagination option, clicking on which we'll hide first column and display 4th column: 2 3 4
and so on. I dont want to use a carousel and display groups of items. I want to show individual items during pagination.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img alt="300x200"  style="height: 200px;width: 100%" src="images/1.png">
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img alt="300x200" style="height: 200px;width: 100%" src="images/2.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img alt="300x200" style="height: 200px;width: 100%" src="images/3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img alt="300x200" style="height: 200px;width: 100%" src="images/4.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img alt="300x200" style="height: 200px;width: 100%" src="images/5.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is using bootstrap 2.4.2. I know that I can only have 3 span4 divs but thats what I am trying to achieve, render 4th and 5th thumbnails after pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to update this question earlier. I was able to solve the problem using jCarousel plugin: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
However, I couldnt use the bootstrap classes for creating the grid layout. Changed the implementation to use lists as suggested by LOTUSMS.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is using lists as the original site you sampled used. If you are going to use divs, give them ids and reference them with AJAX. In the css, use your transition properties to make them slide in/out.

```
.transitions{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
```

or use lists as I suggested and use a carousel jquery but play:off or start:false, whichever the slider uses.

the Fiddle demonstrates their code isolated from the site so you can study it

[SLIDER](http://jsfiddle.net/uLJ7L/)

Comment: Thanks @LOTUSMS, I looked at the jsfiddle example. When I click on next and previous icons nothing happens. (Sorry if this is a noob comment). And the transition you have provided and the ones in the jsfiddle, arent they for the hover effect? Because I dont see an onclick event being handled there. Still trying to figure out how the click is being handled.